# Spring MVC: Getting 406 response while mapping the @PathVariable with url which has ".com" in the last

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, path-variables

I am in a project and getting `HTTP Status 406` in the response when my URL is such like that:

`http://www.mydomain.com/project/website/reply/google.com`

I found its throwing 406 when url ended with `.com, .in` etc, and when the url ended with `.do, .co, .coom` etc, then its response as a HTML page but not mapped the full url

eg: Suppose I have 2 url

1. `http://www.mydomain.com/project/website/reply/google.com`

   // will return 406
2. `http://www.mydomain.com/project/website/reply/apple.do`

   // will return HTML but `.do` will be ignored by `@PathVariable`, so you will get only `apple` in the place on `apple.do`. I want the full value after the `reply/`

As I said that I am getting `HTTP Status 406(The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.)`, So I googled and got some suggestions like `Ignoring accept headers` and `ContentNegotiations`, but still getting the same response.

I am using:

- Spring MVC 3.2.0.RELEASE (with JAVA Config)
- jackson.version 2.1.0
- Thymeleaf Template Engine 2.1.2.RELEASE

Please let me know if you want any other information from my side.

Here is my code for `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` (using this [ref](https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views)) in JAVA config but its not working:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
System.out.println("### configureContentNegotiation is called");
configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(
ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
System.out.println("### contentNegotiatingViewResolver is called");
List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();      
ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());      

// Create the CNVR plugging in the resolvers and the content-negotiation manager
ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
return resolver;
}
```

Please give me some suggestion for this.

Comment: The 406 shouldn't have anything to do with the `@PathVariable`. Its that your browser doesn't support the Content-Type header you are passing back.

Comment: Yes right, but its not the solution of my problem.